# Is importing jersey and jax-rs in service classes considered bad practice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I work with new project and code is a mess. We do some refactoring and one of the requirements is that service layer will not import any jax-rs packages. It is extremely hard to achieve without a complete rewrite of methods in controllers (instead of moving them to services as they are) since the code is one tightly coupled spaghetti. Is it a reasonable requirement or not?

Comment: If you consider traditional "tiered" architecture (Data -> Business -> Presentation), lower layers shouldn't know about higher layers.  Personally, I would stick to this. There's a lot of benefit to this, that's the main reason for using it. If the benefit doesn't outweigh the cost of refactoring, then don't do it. But consider any future cost that would come with scaling and maintaining and problems that the "spaghetti" code would cause.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to apply the Hexagonal (Ports and Adapters) architecture principles to separate the high level concerns, for example, to have:

- The application service layer that contains application service interfaces and their implementations.
- The open host service layer that contains the controller interfaces (depend on JAX-RS API) and their implementations (depend on the JAX-RS API implementation like Jersey, etc): the implementations just use the application service interfaces appropriately.

I would like to recommend you to refer to the book for the further details: 
[«Implementing Domain-Driven Design», 1st Edition, Vaughn Vernon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577). Consider using the keywords: «application service», «open host service», «Hexagonal», «Ports and Adapters».